# Homebrew install fails while copying files

Tags: git, permissions, homebrew

I run this:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get prompt:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
```

After I click "return"(enter button) I get this error:

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: cannot copy '/usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-receive.sample' to '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/hooks/pre-receive.sample': Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q
```

Any ideas what kind of error I am facing and what can be done? It is not really clear for me as it is first time I am facing something like this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are getting permission denied when downloading the files into `/usr/local`.

This folder often belongs to root. This is a known issue with brew. Fix it by doing

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

and then re-run the installer.

Comment: Yup, sir, you are right. Found out that half an hour after posting the question on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: I had to run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` for it to work.

Comment: yes, 'sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local' didn't work for me either. 'sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local' did. Thanks @joran

Comment: If this not working. Try this sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*  This worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I could get it working with

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

thanks to @joran for suggesting this in comments

Comment: If this not working. Try this sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: "operation not permitted" is coming

Answer (score 5):

If nothing works, then just uninstall and install home-brew again.

Uninstall command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Install command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the error message issue trying to update Brew via another Mac user. When I tried entering the above `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`
I got:

```
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
```

I found [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228) `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` which allowed me to perform install of brew for separate Mac user.