# Homebrew installation presented with error

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

On installation of homebrew I am presented with this error, could someone please explain what is happening and the solution?

```html
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: cannot copy '/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.1/share/git-core/templates/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman.sample' to '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman.sample':
 Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592463/homebrew-install-fails-while-copying-files ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to give Homebrew the right to write inside `/usr/local`. To do this the official command to run is:

```
cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks
```

Read the official [troubleshooting page of Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html) for details.

If you have not installed applications in `/usr/local` that rely on specific permissions, you can also run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```